# How to invoke PHP script from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a nagging feeling this has been asked, but I'm not sure how to phrase it correctly, so I'll ask here anyway.

I'm writing a simple calculator script (for learning, I'm newbie), and I split it up into two parts - front end form validation with JS and calculation with PHP.

To be more specific, here are the three parts:

**HTML** (index.php)

```
<form action = "calculator.php" method = "post">
```

First number: Input field here

Operator: Drop down

Second number: Input field here

Submit button

```
</form>
```

**JavaScript** (validate.js)

validate() - regex checks that first and second number are all digits

**PHP** (calculator.php)

Extract first and second number, calculate result, and display on page

Here's my question - I would like to make it such that when the submit button is pressed, the page is passed on to the server ONLY if all regex tests are passed.

Something like:

```
validate() {
    // testing code
    ...
    if first_num_valid == true && second_num_valid == true
        redirect to calculator.php
}
```

How do I do this in Javascript?

Or, if this isn't possible, can you suggest an alternative to this?

Thanks!

**EDIT 1: Tried @joe's solution but not sure how to make it work?**

```
$("#calculator").onsubmit(function() {
    if (first_valid && second_valid)
        return true;
    else 
        return false;
});
```

I assume @joe was trying to say that the form only submit only if the return value is true, but I tried this, but the form submitted whether or not the values were true?

**EDIT 2: For clarification**

index.php

```
<form id = "calculator" action = "./calculation.php" method = "post" >
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>First number</td>
    <td><input type = "text" name = "first_num" id = "first_num"/></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Operator</td>
    <td>
    <select name = "operator">
        <option value = "+" name = "add">+</option>
        <option value = "-" name = "minus">-</option>
        <option value = "*" name = "multiply">*</option>
        <option value = "/" name = "divide">/</option>
    </select>
    </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Second number</td>
    <td><input type = "text" name = "second_num" id = "second_num" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>
    <input type = "submit" name = "submit" id = "submit" onclick = "validate()"/>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

validate.js

```
function validate() {
    var first_num = $("#first_num").val();
    var second_num = $("#second_num").val();

    var regex = new RegExp("^[\\d]+$");

    var first_valid = regex.test(first_num);
    var second_valid = regex.test(second_num);

    var alert_string = "";


    if (!first_valid && second_valid) 
        alert_string += "First number invalid!<br />";
    else if (first_valid && !second_valid)
        alert_string += "Second number invalid!";
    else if (!first_valid && !second_valid)
        alert_string += "Both numbers invalid!";

    if (!first_valid || !second_valid)
        alert(alert_string);

    $("#calculator").onsubmit(function() {
        if (first_valid && second_valid)
            return true;
        else 
            return false;
    });
}
```

EDIT 3: Put all code in handler, didn't work?

```
$("#calculator").on('submit', function() {
    var first_num = $("#first_num").val();
    var second_num = $("#second_num").val();

    var regex = new RegExp("^[\\d]+$");

    var first_valid = regex.test(first_num);
    var second_valid = regex.test(second_num);

    var alert_string = "";

    if (!first_valid && second_valid) 
        alert_string += "First number invalid!";
    else if (first_valid && !second_valid)
        alert_string += "Second number invalid!";
    else if (!first_valid && !second_valid)
        alert_string += "Both numbers invalid!";

    if (!first_valid || !second_valid)
        alert(alert_string);

    if (first_valid && second_valid)
        return true;
    else 
        return false;
});
```

Comment: Have a look for ajax. I'd give you a full answer but it's been done to death.

Comment: I stopped after the title. This question came way to often recently. Retracted the vote.

Comment: **The question has been edited to include jquery**. That changes a lot!

Comment: @blazonix don't forget to select an answer as "accepted" if your problem was solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an answer for your form validation question.

First, give your form an id so that you can identify it.

```
<form id="calculator_form" action="calculator.php" method="post">
```

Then, attach a submit handler for that form. If the submit handler fails, the form will not submit.

```
document.getElementById('calculator_form').onsubmit = function() {
  if (!first_num_valid) {
    return false;
  }
  if (!second_num_valid) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

---

OK now your question edit has jquery. That changes my answer here.

```
$("#calculator").on('submit', function() {
    if (first_valid && second_valid) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I'm confused - does this mean that if the return value is false, the form won't be submitted, and if it is true, it will? I just tried adding this code snippet (rephrased, I've put it up in the edits section, but the form submits whether the input is valid or not). What I'd like is for the form to only submit when both are valid? Thanks!

Comment: You are correct in your assessment. As for why it is not working for you: Are you putting this snippet in the head of your html, or is it after the form? This will not work if the javascript comes before the form, since the form doesn't exist when the javascript runs!

Comment: It's within the form tags, if that answers your question :) The validate function is also within the form tags called with onclick event on the submit button

Comment: Your script tag is within your form tag? Move that to the bottom of the page.

Comment: Oh no, it's in the onclick = "validate" in the input tag. Does this change things? And why did you say jQuery changes things?

Comment: Okay, now I have another problem - if you enter the right input - you get sent to the results page, and if you go back and enter wrong input, a message pops up, but if you enter right input again, it doesn't work. Any suggestions as to why this may be??

Comment: StackOverflow has rules about answering with jquery if the original question does not use jquery. In the past there have been some problems: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Bzawb.gif

Comment: I see, sorry about that

Comment: I see your edit to your question. Now your problem is with variable scope. `first_valid` and `second_valid` are scoped in the validate function, and are not accessible in the submit handler. You should remove the `onclick` from the submit button, remove the `validate` function, and put all of that validation code into the submit handler.

Comment: I tried editing it as per your suggestion, but it didn't work - now the validation doesn't happen at all - I tried combing through the code but can't seem to see the problem?

Comment: Works in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SmJ8a/ and that's just copy/pasted from your question.

Comment: Okay...now I'm lost - I tried running a simple alert function in $(document).ready(function(){alert('a')}); and it doesn't work...I'm sure I included the jQuery libraries correctly...and the path names are right. I think I'll come back to this tomorrow when I have a clearer mind, but thanks for the help @Joe :)

Comment: use `<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript" /></script>` and **make sure** that (1) the jQuery library is saved as jquery.js and (2) is in **the same directory** as your present file and (3) that this line is executed before your jQuery code

Answer (score 1):

**[AJAX!](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)** (a basic AJAX call in jQuery)

```
function validate() {
    // testing code
        if (yourRegexTest == true) {
        $.ajax({
        url: "calculator.php?data1=" + jsVar1 + "&data2=" + jsVar2; // ...etc
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {

           // data[0] now carries the php variable $newVar1 (below)
           // data[1] now carries $newVar2 (below)
           // do stuff with data[0] and data[1];
           return false; // do not submit the form. The ajax call does what you want pressing the submit button to effectively do.
        }


        });
        } else {  alert('regex check failed');
                  return false; // do not submit the form. regex check failed.
                  }
}
```

**calculator.php**

```
<?php
$var1 = $_GET['data1']; $var2 = $_GET['data2'];
$newVar1 = dostuffto($var1);
$newVar2 = dostuffto($var2);
echo json_encode(array($var1,$var2));
?>
```

Also -- *"Here's my question - I would like to make it such that when the submit button is pressed, the page is passed on to the server ONLY if all regex tests are passed."*

On the submit button use `<input type="submit" id="myID" value="sumbit" onclick="return validate();"/>`

When you `return` a JS function on an `onclick` event for a `submit` button as above, the form **will not** be submitted unless that function returns `true`. In my example the form never gets "submitted", but rather, the AJAX call is run only if the regex check passes.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question. It answers the question's title, but not the question's content.

Comment: @JoeFrambach -- made some edits with further answers

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is what you would want to look at to send things asynchronously to PHP.  Here is [jQuery's API](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) on the subject.  Gather your form info, submit it with AJAX, and put in your callback functions to capture what PHP kicks out (which you will use to display to the user on screen).

One side note I would like to offer though is that you do some validation on the server side.  It certainly isn't a bad thing to do any validation with JS on the client side, but malicious users can circumvent your validation.  My suggestion for validation is to do some basics with JS, but make sure PHP is sanitizing/validating the input properly.

**EDIT**

---

I have a version of this you can take a look at that uses native JS (as your question originally started as).  You appear to need AJAX, but looking at your question it looks like you wish to simply submit the form.  I say this because there seems to be no immediate place in your code where a return value would be delivered.

Anyhow, the basic idea is to get both of your values from your number fields, check them as number, and then submit.  Give this a try:

```
<form id = "calculator" action = "./calculation.php" method = "post" onsubmit="return validate()" >
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>First number</td>
    <td><input type = "text" name = "first_num" id = "first_num"/></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Operator</td>
    <td>
    <select name = "operator">
        <option value = "+" name = "add">+</option>
        <option value = "-" name = "minus">-</option>
        <option value = "*" name = "multiply">*</option>
        <option value = "/" name = "divide">/</option>
    </select>
    </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Second number</td>
    <td><input type = "text" name = "second_num" id = "second_num" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>
    <input type = "submit" name = "submit" id = "submit" />
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function validate()
    {
        var num1 = document.getElementById('first_num').value;
        var num2 = document.getElementById('second_num').value;
        if(!isNaN(num1) && !isNaN(num2)) {
            alert("Numbers!");
            return true;
        }
        alert("Fail!");
        return false;
    }

</script>
```

Hope that helps.  I still can stress enough that in a real-life application you should really rely on server side validation of data.

Comment: @blazonix I've edited my answer and took it back to the roots of where your question started.  I hope that helps you out.